# graphics program by OpenGL without windows programming

Tags: c, opengl, graphics

I want to do graphics program by OpenGL. But I don't have any experienced in windows programming. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you get the Windows compiler this includes some demo programs. You can use one of these as a holder for your OpenGL window. You can avoid Windows programming by sticking to using of of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these links

- [lazy foo tutorial for SDL](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/) to simplify some file and inputs handling
- [SDL and OpenGL](http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-opengl-tutorial-basics)
- [Kore engine](http://code.google.com/p/kore2engine/) uses Opengl and SDL and is open source
- [Kore Engine wiki](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL%3aTutorials%3aComplete_2D_Engine_Graphics_Core) Some more info on the Kore Engine
- [My own project](http://code.google.com/p/getrandomgame/) using SDL and OPENGL host on Google code

Note that you'll need to code in C++ with those links

---

EDIT:

I tried GLUT and SFML, and both are easier to use than SDL and OpenGL alone.

GLUT is pretty straightforward but is limited in its scope.

SFML brings the good things of SDL and OpenGL, but with a nice C++ interface instead of the old C interface of SDL and raw OpenGL calls (which are still possible to do). Big performance gain out of the box for the same project, SFML is just better optimized than my own code with SDL.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't have any experienced in windows programming. Any suggestion?

Well, you need to create a window somehow, so that the user can see the beautiful pictures you'll draw using OpenGL. But you're right: Opening a window and creating a OpenGL context is tedious, no matter which OS you're doing it on (the most simple one would be probably NSOpenGLView of MacOS X).

Luckily there are some libraries that abstract away the OS dependent parts of creating a window and creating and attaching a OpenGL context to it.

- GLUT is probably the oldest one of those. I discourage using the original GLUT and recommend to use FreeGLUT or OpenGLUT instead, as those are actively maintained. They are easy to use. But GLUT don't give you control over the event loop which essentially means, it's ill suited for creating games.
- SDL is actually a whole bunch of sub-libraries, the main library providing creating of windows. Also provides OpenGL support, but has not been tailored for it. Personally these days I'd use SDL for everything but creation of a OpenGL window. But it's fine for audio, loading graphics and such.
- GLFW is IMHO one of the nicest OpenGL frameworks out there. It has a well designed API, gives you full control over the event loop and is actively maintained. Also it focuses on exactly one task: Create a OpenGL window and provide a message pump for user input.

Comment: SFML is also a great library to use.  I think it's approaching a release of version 2.0.

Comment: SFML 2.1 has just been released. I switch my own project from SDL to SFML this summer. Best idea we had yet.